# NullPointerException with JDBC and App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have been struggling with a problem in Google App Engine, using Java, for several days.

Many times (about 50% of the time) when I try to request the connection to a Cloud Sql instance, the connection returns a null value, resulting in several NullPointerException messages when trying to invoke Cloud Sql queries (when invoking .prepareCall(stored_proc)).

I have the latest App Engine Java SDK, in a project service, shared with other services built in Python which consume this Java backend.

Could it be possible that after certain time the instance/s could crash (I am just testing at this point, so I am using default scalation)?

This is the code that returns null:

```
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
        url = "jdbc:google:mysql://project:instance/database?user=root";
        log.info(url);
        return DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

This is part of my configuration file:

```
<application>app</application>
<module>mod</module>
<version>1</version>
<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>

<use-google-connector-j>true</use-google-connector-j>
```

I tried several suggestions from other posts, but with no success at all.

Any suggestion will be welcome, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will add this as an answer, since it is not exactly what Chrispinus mentioned, although he gave me a good idea for teh solution.

I went deeper in the code and found that some of the methods were not closing the database connection. I had assumed all of them were doing that, but looking at each method, I found I was wrong.

So, although it sounds obvious, check connections are being closed (or managed, as Chrispinus says) properly.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem while using Google Cloud SQL and App engine.

I solved the problem by managing the connection pool my self. I realised that when you request a new connection for each request and close it on completion of the thread. The other requests would get back a null resulting to NullPointException.

I  decided to do the following and it work for me for like 2 years now.

- Open a connection and keep it to a static class that has a number of connections;
- Every time i want to find a connection to the database, i would first check if the is an available connection for me to use.
- Incase a Query killed the connection, thus means i needed to request another extra connection just to for the sack of connection drops.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Chrispinus, I can certainly try that and see what happens, will let you know. Just another question: Do you have a connection limit in you app? How did you deal with that? App Engine allows a maximum number of 12 concurrent connections per instance, if I remember well.